# Why can't I login on software and websites?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, internet-connection

I am using XP SP2, and everything where working fine. Somehow I can go to some web pages, but I can't login to them, for example `www.buzzerbeater.com`, I can't access my Hotmail / Windows Live, Outlook doesn't work either, also `www.realgm.com`, I can't access the forums too. I have tried with IE7 / Firefox / Chrome, but same result. I was using avast free edition that I removed, and I don't have any other security software installed.

My laptop from the same network works perfectly. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you **sure** you're inputting the correct username/password?

Comment: More details please, what happens if you try to login? Does it work, and you just don't stay logged in f.e.?

Comment: Sorry if this is too much a basic question, but are you sure caps lock is not on? Other thing is (as already mentioned) you or someone restricted https (or other service/protocol) in the router firewall, software firewall, or it's happening in a proxy. Sometimes, a weird proccess and/or service(you need to be very sure that it is actually suspicious, and not a windows one) has been installed by a virus. You may just stop those. Often is needed for that to boot in safe mode.

Answer (score 1):

Virus.  You need to take your machine off the internet, download a proper virus scanner/removal tool and see if it's salvageable.  Might be quicker just to back up your data and reformat.

Comment: You might want to *download* that virus scanner *before* you take the machine off the Internet ;)

Comment: @torbengb Actually, no! The proper way would be to download the virus scanner from another computer, to make sure the scanner itself isn't infected! :)

Comment: The old good way was actually make a boot floppy disk in a safe computer, using an antivirus, and load the infected machine with the floppy disk inserted. Yet though I usually don't need to require that.

Comment: @S.gfx The good old way would hardly be doable these days

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention which browser you are using, which is really the most important data.

Try launching your browser in Safe mode or "no add-ons", according to the browser you have. If this start working, then the problem is with some add-on that you are using.

You can also try resetting your browser to default values, or try another browser, to better pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest a different antivirus too, look at using something like Microsoft Security Essentials, but I wouldn't type any more passwords in there until you've done a scan. If you can get access to the accounts from another PC, change the passwords ASAP

Answer (score 0):

I would first try the Virus checking suggestions above - but should that fail to turn up anything, have you recently installed a firewall or similar? It could be anything you have recently installed. Also - is this all sites that require HTTPS?
One last important thing - are you still able to log in to those sites on another computer *after* having tried on the problem computer?